# Inspection seems to ignore namespace naming preferences

Tags: c#, namespaces, resharper, naming-conventions

**Update:** It seems as if there's actually a bug in ReSharper: [Naming rules for namespaces are ignored](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468386).
'Inconsistent Naming' inspection currently just does not work in ReSharper 2017.3.2

---

Currently using ReSharper 2017.3.2 on VS 2012 Professional. After changing the namespace and class name in this very simple example, ReSharper inspection seems to ignore the namespace starting with an lower case letter. Nevertheless it seems to recognize the class name starting with an lower clase letter. Am I doing something wrong here. I'd like the inspection to recognize lower case namespace definitions too.

```
namespace resharperDemo.demo
{
    public class program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Naming style settings:

[image: settings]

Inspection result:

[image: Inspection result]

Answer (score 0):

Go to Resharper->Options->Code Editing->C#->Naming Style:

[image]

Above is my default configuration. You can match yours.

Comment: same settings here. Inspection keeps complaining only about type name `program`.

Comment: @verm-luh you can try restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: @verm-luh Can you try resetting Resharper to default settings using following link: https://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206062629-How-do-I-reset-resharper-to-factory-defaults-

If it works I can include it in my answer as well.

Comment: Resetting Resharper settings showed no effect. Can you please confirm your installation recognizes namespace definitions starting with lower case letters?

Comment: @verm-luh I created a namespace `hello` but it doesn't show me anything.

Comment: Thank you for your confirmation. It seems as if there's actually a bug in ReSharper [Naming rules for namespaces are ignored](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468386)